Obtaining the conversion matrix when we have two vectors
I have a vector, and I physically know what the new version of that vector will be after changing the space. I want to find a matrix that converts that vector to the new one, and it should be true for three vectors at the same time. How can I do that in Mathematica?
As more clarification: I am trying to obtain primitive vectors from conventional ones in my crystal with tetragonal symmetry. I know the conventional 3 vectors which are describing the crystal structure and I can obtain primitive because from the text book I know it is :

But I need a matrix that converts conventional to primitive to be able to convert other vectors as well.
I appreciate your help
**I am doing all of these in reciprocal space

One can use LinearSolve for this.

Assuming you want to find $A$ s.t. $AC = P$ where $C$ is the conventional and $P$ is the primitive, you can just use $A = P C^{-1}$. Note that $C$ is diagonal so the inverse is just 1 over the diagonal elements.

I am not very experienced in crystallography, but I think this is simply a basis change. Let us define:
b1 = {a, 0, 0};
b2 = {0, a, 0};
b3 = {0, 0, c};
p1 = {-a, a, c}/2;
p2 = {a, -a, c}/2;
p3 = {a, a, -c}/2;

Now, any vector may be written in both basis b and p with coefficients cb and cp (note: cbi and cp1 are scalars, bit bi and pi are vectors):
vec == {cp1, cp2, cp3} . {p1, p2, p3} == {cb1, cb2, cb3} . {b1, b2, b3}

If we multiply from the right with the inverse of {p1,p2,p3}:
{cp1, cp2, cp3} == {cb1, cb2, cb3}.{b1, b2, b3}.Inverse[{p1, p2, p3}]

Or if we prefer to have the coefficients on the right, we may transpose the right side:
{cp1, cp2, cp3} == 
 Transpose[{b1, b2, b3} . Inverse[{p1, p2, p3}]] . {cb1, cb2, cb3}

therefore, the transformation matrix for coefficients b to c is:
coefb2p=  Transpose[{b1, b2, b3} . Inverse[{p1, p2, p3}]]

{{0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}}

Let us check this. With an arbitrary vector with coef. {1,2,3} in base b and äa,2a,3c} in the original basis:
vec1== {1,2,3}.{b1,b2,b3} == {a, 2 a, 3 c}

we get the p components by:
coefb2p . {1,2,3}

{5, 4, 3}

Or again in the original basis:
{5,4,3} . {p1,p2,p3}

{a, 2 a, 3 c}


You can define your lattices as matrices, and then use Solve:
amat = {{a, 0, 0}, {0, a, 0}, {0, 0, c}};
prim = {{-a/2, a/2, c/2}, {a/2, -a/2, c/2}, {a/2, a/2, -c/2}};
ar = Array[map, {3, 3}];
sol = Solve[ar . amat == prim, Flatten[ar, 1]];
ar /. sol[[1]]

{{-(1/2), 1/2, 1/2}, {1/2, -(1/2), 1/2}, {1/2, 1/2, -(1/2)}}


Expanding on my comment, notice, conventional is diagonal with diagonal elements diag
diag = {a, a, c};
conventional = DiagonalMatrix[diag];
primitive = (1 - 2 IdentityMatrix[3])/2 * Threaded[diag];

So the solution mat to mat.conventional == primitive is just the primitive dotted with 1 over the diagonal elements (since that's the inverse of conventional):
mat = primitive . DiagonalMatrix[1/diag]


{{-(1/2), 1/2, 1/2}, {1/2, -(1/2), 1/2}, {1/2, 1/2, -(1/2)}}

mat . conventional == primitive


True

You can also derive mat by just noticing how I wrote out primitive:
(1 - 2 IdentityMatrix[3])/2 == mat


True

